# cakePHP - 404- page not found error, when deploying on a different machine

Tags: cakephp, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to deploy a cakephp application into my peers system and i get 404 error, for all requests. **This is not cakephp 404 error, but a normal webserver 404 page not found error.** :( . We both use MAC OS 10.6. The same code works on my machine and on the production system. I have followed the steps to deploy on his machine. I'm using cakephp advanced installation, i.e, webroot contain only index.php, css, js,etc. The APP folder and CAKE folder is located elsewhere.

1. uncommented the line "LoadModule php5_module...." in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
2. Changed to AllowOverride All to the Directory - "Library/WebServer/Documents" in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
3. uncommented and set date.timezone in /etc/php.ini
4. Copied the webroot contents to "Library/WebServer/Documents" and modified index.php to adapt to his machine (setup 3 relevant paths to the CORE, APP and CAKE folder)
5. made sure the DB connection is good.
6. For debugging purpose, Modified core.php and set Configure::write('debug',3);

The homepage get data from an AJAX call. WHen i goto http://localhost, the header and footer contents from the layouts/default.ctp are rendered, but the ajax call which is for example http://localhost/posts/showmyposts gets a 404 (Not Found) error. If I goto to other URLs like http://localhost/users/login, I get the normal webserver 404 error.

**Not Found**

The requested URL /users/login/ was not found on this server.

In my apache error log, i get the error as

[Mon May 16 16:19:48 2011] [error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/users, referer: http://localhost/
Is my cakephp installation correct ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with `mod_rewrite` not working on that machine. What happens when you try to run a default Cake install? Does it load the CSS and all?

Is there a `.htaccess` file in your app directory (and in your webroot directory)?

Do you have `FollowSymLinks` turned on in your Apache config files?

Comment: My webroot folder is missing .htaccess file. Thank you very much ! Everything works great now.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by creating an .htaccess in public_html folder, with the following content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        #Rewrite CakePHP
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !server-status
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had to modify my httpd.conf file (it's location varies on your Linux installation-- mine was at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf) in **two** places to get this to work on CentOS.

In addition to the `<Directory /var/www>` as mentioned in the CakePHP docs, if you go a little further down you'll see `<Directory "/var/www/html">` which does not allow rewriting.

Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.

Be sure to reset apache using `sudo /sbin/service httpd restart`.

Comment: Thanks man!. Only your solution from all solutions here worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

*If the above solutions have no effect*, **make sure the apache rewrite module is enabled**

On debian it is disabled by default

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I ran into the fact that all posts controller requests (/posts/*) were returning 404. Other controller pages were working fine.

Turns out it was because I had a posts.sql file floating around in my web root. As soon as I moved the file, everything worked. Even with the .sql extension, Cake's rewrite rules made the request map to a non-existent posts folder.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience