# cake php gives me error when setting up on development server

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu-12.04, apache2.4

First of all, I want to describe that I have researched a lot on this question so thats why I am asking so please dont downvote. I have implemented lot of solutions.

I am using cake2.0. I have uploaded a website on development server the link is http://dev.infideaco.com/eventmanager/ . But I am getting the not found error. I have resolved it by changing the .htaccess files but then the css,js and images are still not available.

I have .htaccess files which are provided by default installation. I am setting it up in development server 
/var/www/dev.infideaco.com/eventmanager

The website is running fine on other servers.
You can check here:
http://swirlsyogurtbar.com/js/
These are the htaccess files:

```
root file:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule sss   (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
in app:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$  webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
app/webroot/.htaccess:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please provide me the solution. Lot of thanks in advance

Comment: Share directory structure inside /var/www/dev.infideaco.com/eventmanager and also share all .htaccess files

Comment: Thanks for your trying to help me out.
I have shared the .htaccess file now .
Please see me question again with my updated htaccess files..

Comment: Could you please share error logs, tail -f  /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if server supports mod_rewrite. Also check this thread if you haven't already: [cakePHP - 404- page not found error, when deploying on a different machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022579/cakephp-404-page-not-found-error-when-deploying-on-a-different-machine)

Comment: server supports mod_rewrite.I will let you know the .htacess files here.
root folder:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

in app/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>

in app/webroot/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I have just updated my htacces files please take a look there. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

root file:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
     RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

in app:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$  webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

app/webroot/.htaccess:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have updated the files but now it is showing this error just the path has been changed:
The requested URL /app/webroot/index.php was not found on this server.
You can check on the live url path